# Passing Subreport Value to Main Report

Tags: crystal-reports

In my Report I am passing the Total of Subreport to display in the Main Report for that I am using the below Formula,

In Subreport,

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared Numbervar EvTotal:= cdbl({Evaluation_Details.NOOFCOPIESEVALUATED})
```

In Main Report,

```
Shared NumberVar EvTotal;
EvTotal;
```

but when I Include the Formula for displaying in the Main Report it is Dispalying "0" instead of Total of SubReport

Comment: are you showing the extotal before or after the subreport?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of things:
You have some typos in your code. Here you were missing the semi-colon at the end:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared Numbervar EvTotal:= cdbl({Evaluation_Details.NOOFCOPIESEVALUATED});
```

And here you don't need the semi-colon:

```
Shared NumberVar EvTotal;
EvTotal
```

And as @Raphael pointed out, it is important that you have the subreport higher in the hierarchy than the formula in the Main Report that calls the variable. I would also suggest to have "WhileReadingRecords;" in both, that way you ensure they evaluate at the same time. Also, as a little debugging help, put "EvTotal" at the end of the first formula, that way you can see what the value is/should be.

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you created in the sub-report must be placed in the detail section or Group header. You can hide this field. Then it will show up the correct value.