# Pass values from sub-report to main-report using crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using crystal report xi. I have made a report with two sub report. The sub reports have summary fields named **sub total**. And i want to make make ***grand total***. How it is possible?
[Sample Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PawSa.jpg)

Comment: Store values in array in sub report and pass on to main report there retrive and sum the data in footer

Answer (score 1):

I may not be able to answer specifically to your requirement: But following are links that show you how to achieve it. You will have to work your way. **The idea is to use Shared variables between main report and subreports.**

Hope it helps you.

See links below:

[Link 1](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3339035)

http://scn.sap.com/people/prabhat.kumar2/blog/2011/11/06/passing-values-between-reports-in-crystal-reports-2008

http://scn.sap.com/people/ashish.bamzai/blog/2011/11/23/passing-values-between-reports-crystal-reports-2008

http://scn.sap.com/people/brian.bischof/blog/2010/09/29/troubleshooting-crystal-reports-shared-variables

[Passing Subreport Value to Main Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560075/passing-subreport-value-to-main-report)