# Crystal: value from Subreport to Main for use in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a subreport with a field called Qty not FBA that is grouped by Customer.  I have used the group sort expert to show me only the top customer (the one with the most qty).

I tried what I found in the post "Passing Subreport Value to Main Report" but am still getting zeros. I am guessing it is because the sort to see only the top customer needs to be included in my code but I don't know how to do that.

I would like to pass that through to the main report for use in a formula. From what I have read elsewhere, I have created a field in the subreport:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar PctofTotal := PercentOfSum ({@Qty not FBA}, {CUSTOMERS.NAME})
```

and a field in the main report:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar PctofTotal;
PctofTotal
```

It is returning zero. I am guessing it is because the sort to only show the top one doesn't work with "While printing records" but I don't know how to get around that. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Subreport Value to Main Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560075/passing-subreport-value-to-main-report)

Comment: I tried that, and edited my description - see the second paragraph.

Comment: Is your subreport suppressed by any chance?  A suppressed subreport will function this way with variables.

Comment: The subreport is not suppressed.

Comment: Where is the delimiter in the first statement {CUSTOMERS.NAME}); ?